# WebServices subsystem disabled in Wildfly 23/24 (Jakarta JWS)

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I am trying to deploy an extremely simple SOAP Web Service, using Jakarta JWS 3.0.0 on OpenJDK 15, to a clean Wildfy 23/24 instance. The code is as follows:

Interface:

```
import jakarta.jws.WebMethod;
import jakarta.jws.WebService;
import jakarta.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import jakarta.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface HelloWorldServerInt {

    @WebMethod
    String sayHelloWorld(String name);
}
```

Implementation:

```
import jakarta.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "ws.HelloWorldServerInt")
public class HelloWorldServerImpl implements HelloWorldServerInt {

    @Override
    public String sayHelloWorld(String name) {
        return "Hello World ! My name is " + name + ".";
    }

}
```

Once I deploy the WAR, I can see it under "Deployments" in the admin console. But if you click "Views / Management Model", under "subsystem", the "webservices" subsystem is disabled, so I cannot see the deployed service, and of course it doesn't work.

I've worked with Web Services before using `web.xml` file and `com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet` servlet, but as far as I know, this is not the way to go, and annotations should be automatically discovered by Wildfly. Am I wrong?

Kind regards.

Comment: Are you using WildFly preview because jakarta isn't supported in the plain WildFly distribution ? Also I'm not sure about Java 15 support given the amount of work still in progress for Java 17 support.

Comment: Last test was made with Widlfy 24.0.1.Final

Comment: but not wildfly-preview-24.0.1.Final (https://download.jboss.org/wildfly/24.0.1.Final/wildfly-preview-24.0.1.Final.zip)

Comment: @ehsavoie Not. I have downloaded it but now I have to configure it, because I am not able to use maven provisioning plugin with preview (an error regarding wildfly-feature-pack.xml). I'll let you know if it works!

Comment: Could you please fill a bug about the provisioning issue you are encountering ?

Comment: Sure, it would be here, right? https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-build-tools/issues

Answer (score 0):

As @ehsavoie explained in the comments, the problem was using Wildfly 24 instead of Wildfly **Preview** 24.

Once everything was set up with WF Preview, Web services subsystem was enabled and usable as expected.